# My event in setAttribute is not working

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I have another query, I wanted to set the attribute of my element with an event, I tried this one 
`textbox1.setAttribute("onclick","save_data(event,this)");`

but still it doesnt work. Can you help me whats the proper way to do this here is my function.

```
function save_data(e, x){
            if(e.keyCode == 13)
            {
                save_fnc(x);
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addEventListener()` for attach the hanlder to element on particular event.

```
textbox1.addEventListener('click', function (e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
      save_fnc(this);
      e.preventDefault();
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For onclick you can directly use

```
 textbox1.onclick=function(e){
 //do required work
 }
```